# Change div border image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the next div shape:

```
#prueba {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-right: 200px solid red;
        border-bottom: 200px solid red;
        position: absolute;
        top:200px;
        left:500px;
        -webkit-border-image: url(img/borde.jpg)  ; /* Safari 3.1-5 */
        -o-border-image: url(img/borde.jpg)  ; /* Opera 11-12.1 */
        border-image: url(img/borde.jpg)  ;
    }
    #prueba:after {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-top: 100px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
        border-left:  50px solid red;
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        top: 0px;
        left: 200px;
    }
```

My goal is to set a image as the background of that div. I search on internet and find a way to change the border image. The problem is that image is set only at `#prueba`.

How I can set the image to all div? Any way to make it more simple?

Actually i have this
 [image]

This is how it looks like when i add the border-image
 [image]

Is the same as asking to aply a background image to any of this shapes(not the square....): https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: I'd suggest looking at w3Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp ?

Comment: To all divs? `div {background: url();}`

Comment: where is the image

Comment: can you give the screenshot of your expected output so that it can be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While searching how to apply the background to all div I found another way to do it:

Creating a normal div and changing the `clip-path`.

```
#prueba {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
   background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
   top:200px;
   left:500px;
   background-color: red;
   background-image: url(img/borde.jpg);
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

This is the result of it.
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwpYK.png)

Still can't figure it out how to do it by the other way

Answer (score 2):

if you want to attach background image to #prueba then you should add some width and height to #prueba,
for set background image to all div you should add same class to all div and then attach background image to that class like below

```
/

/ .html
       <div class="bgClass">
       </div>
       <div class="bgClass">
       </div>
       <div class="bgClass">
       </div>
// style.css

div.bgClass{
        background-image: url(path);
        //other properties
    }
```

Comment: I want to change to border-background, since that shape is constructed using borders

Answer (score 1):

You could associate a class to your div, like "general" or something right in the beggining. Then you apply the style to them, and if for some reason you decide to create a new div without the background image, you still can.

It would look like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="general">
..code..
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div .general{
/* Here you define the background for all gerenal div */
background-image: url (...);
background-position: center;
}
```

----------------//-----------------

Update: I did a simulation with your code and it worked fine for me.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="prueba.css">
<body>
<div id="prueba"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Css:
Exactly what you posted in question.

[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSYvh.jpg)

Comment: There is only 1 div there. That shape is created using borders ( Im don't find another way to do it). Changing the background is like changin nothing, because the image is set to to the border , and the red color u see is the border color aswell.

Comment: Did you try "!important" after you background-image definition?

Comment: There is no background in that div. They are all borders

Comment: Yes yes, sorry. What about definying the height and width? Like "border-image: url("...") 50 50"

Comment: Still having the same problem, Since they are 2 elements. The problem is not how to set a border-image, is how to set to to both elements, so the they look like only 1

Comment: That's weird. I just created all files here and it worked fine with the code you have.

Comment: I already have that result, look the image, the idea is to set the image to all, u still have the red part

Comment: AAh! got it now! sorry.

Comment: Well.. I did some research and it looks like transparence won't work with borders. The best way is to create and superimpose 2 css elements (square + triangle). Good luck. :)

Comment: Thats is already done, there is a square and a triangle there :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the background to set to all `<div>`, you may try this:

```css
.divs{
  text-align: center;
  background: url('https://www.globalbrigades.org/media_gallery/thumb/320/0/Water_2014_Icon_Small.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="divs">
    DIV1DIV1DIV1<br>
    DIV1DIV1DIV1<br>
    DIV1DIV1DIV1<br>
    DIV1DIV1DIV1<br>
    DIV1DIV1DIV1<br>
    DIV1DIV1DIV1<br>
    DIV1DIV1DIV1<br>
    DIV1DIV1DIV1<br>
    DIV1DIV1DIV1<br>
    DIV1DIV1DIV1<br>
    DIV1DIV1DIV1<br>
    DIV1DIV1DIV1<br>
  </div>
  <br><br><br><br>
  <div class="divs">
    DIV2DIV2DIV2<br>
    DIV2DIV2DIV2<br>
    DIV2DIV2DIV2<br>
    DIV2DIV2DIV2<br>
    DIV2DIV2DIV2<br>
    DIV2DIV2DIV2<br>
    DIV2DIV2DIV2<br>
    DIV2DIV2DIV2<br>
    DIV2DIV2DIV2<br>
    DIV2DIV2DIV2<br>
    DIV2DIV2DIV2<br>
    DIV2DIV2DIV2<br>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can do it like that, so every `<div>` with a class of `.divs` will automatically get the background. Please comment below if you have problem with this. Happy coding! :)

Comment: You updated your question. Please provide more information so we can figure it out. Please edit your question. Make it more clearly.

Comment: @CristianS9 It is also just an example, otherwise you can remove other `<div>`s :)

Comment: Look the code to see how is that div created. There is only one div. Created using 2 element. so changin that elemnts border that shape is obtained. So there is no background in that div, only borders

Answer (score 0):

Let insert background inside your div #prueba

Try this

```
#prueba {
    ...
    background-image: url('your/image/path');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    ...
}
```

Comment: or change #prueba to div

Comment: That was my first idea,but how to reach that shape using only div? with no borders?

Comment: thats already in the code, the problem is how to aply to all div

Comment: OK, try again.. you try to change selector in css from #prueba to div or body * {....;}

Comment: There is only one div in that code. The shape of that div is created using 2 elements, changin their border. There is no background there, so changing the background image make no difference. Changing the first element border-image only set the background to half of the div. So problem is how to set the background to both elements of that div so it is diplayed combined

Comment: I just see something.. **in your CSS** the border-image property. You must write be string ex. url('path/to/image'); Try this!

Comment: The url work, the question here is how to aply to both elementes: all div